# Handling large data and displaying in a dynamic table

Tags: angular

Using angular 6 here.

In my UI I am creating dynamic table with dynamic rows and columns. So a user can add any number of rows and columns and then add data to the rows.
The am using FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup to build this in angular. The table is something similar to as :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmfjhh-mtjvbl?file=app/table-basic-example.html. This all works fine.

```
 <table >
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of displayedHead"> {{col}}</th>
    </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let element of myformArray.controls;let i=index">
    <td *ngFor="let col of displayedFields">  
      <input arrow-div [formControl]="element.get(col)">
    </td>
  <td>
        <button arrow-div (click)="delete(i)">delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now user wanted an option of uploading csv file to this table. So I used ng2 file upload for this. User selects an csv file with colums and rows and then upload this.
The file is sent back to my C# web api where I process the incoming data and return json. I then bind back the json returned to the table. All of this also works fine.

The issue is when there is large amount of data in the csv file. Say more than 1000 rows (rows can be more than 10k as well). When I upload this, the api returns the processed json fine but the 
UI takes a long time and many a times freezes when it tries to rebuild this table and bind so many rows and columns to the table.

Right now I am not looking at any third party solutions to this problem. I know I have to introduce paging to my table. What I am not sure is the best approach for this.
Say there are 50k rows in the CSV to be uploaded. Should the api process and return all the rows back to the UI and then UI would handle this via paging (will the web/http able to handle such data in memory)
Or should the API just send out chunks of data depeding on the UI paging. Say initally just send 500 rows, then on next page click another 500 and so. But this would involve several trips to the server.

Would appreciate if the someone can provide the right approach/examples.

Comment: I'm of the mindset of always fetching only what is requested. Get the 500 (we 1000) if the user wants more data they request more data. Reason being lets say there are 50k records and the user only needed to view 100 that's 49900 extra records transferred  unnecessarily. It only involves as many trips to the server as needed by the user. Definitely use paging, sorting, filtering.

Comment: Thanks. I would start with paging and data on demand restricting data to page level.  Will look at other methods of caching etc if required.

Comment: Actually we perform a query giving the user back a preliminary count. E.g. your search will return 1million records do you want to retrieve them or modify your query. If they choose to retrieve then it would perform paging and pull first 500 and pull so on and so on for each page request.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain opinions which I have implemented while implementing grid

1. Show only the requested data i.e. 50 or 100 rows as required, because showing all the records is not a good user experience at all.
2. To save the server round trips you can use Redux ( considered very good library for managing state of the application) store using which will store the whole response from the API.The advantage of using this is you can paginate and filter the data without making the server round trips.
3. You can create your own constant service to store the API response and then query the response on client side
4. If you dont want to store the data on the client side then you can enable caching on the server side and then query the response as and when needed for the specific requests made.